# jquery-datatables-rails sort arrows not showing up in development environment

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

I have a new rails install. I followed the instructions on this page exactly: https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

When I try to view a datatable, I get these errors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/sort_both.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/images/sort_asc.png 404 (Not Found)
```

In `config/environments/development.rb` I've tried changing the following settings:

```
config.assets.debug = false #and also tried true
config.serve_static_assets = true #and also tried false
config.assets.enabled = true
```

I've also tried running `rake assets:precompile`

Not sure what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps someone will present a better answer. This is how I fixed it.

I got rid of the gem. Downloaded the javascript and css files from the [datatables website](http://www.datatables.net/):

- [jquery.dataTables.min.css](http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css)
- [jquery.dataTables.min.js](http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

Put these files in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` and `vendor/assets/javascripts` respectively.

I downloaded the [missing images from here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/datatables) and stuck them in my `vendor/assets/images` folder that I created.

I did a replace all on the text in `jquery.dataTables.min.css` and replaced "/images/" with "/assets/"

And that fixed it. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I change vendor/assets/stylesheets/plugins/dataTables.bootstrap.css
Replace  'background: url('../images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right;' with  'background: url('/assets/images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right;'

Answer (score 1):

**1. Download Image From Here :**

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/datatables

[image]

**2. create datatable folder inside assets and put images inside it**

[image]

**3. in your style.scss or style.css add below code :**

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
    background-image: url("./assets/datatable/sort_both.png");
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
    background-image: url("./assets/datatable/sort_asc.png") !important;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
    background-image: url("./assets/datatable/sort_desc.png") !important;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled {
    background-image: url("./assets/datatable/sort_asc_disabled.png");
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
    background-image: url("./assets/datatable/sort_desc_disabled.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it using a different version of the [jquery.dataTables.min.css](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/lib/datatables/css/default/jquery.dataTables.min.css) file, where the images are written as strings rather than as references to a file.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked just by changing the below:

```
background:url('../images/sort_desc.png')
background:url('../images/sort_asc.png')
```

to

```
background:url('/assets/sort_desc.png')
background:url('/assets/sort_asc.png')
```

NOTE: please make sure you add the images to **assets/images** folder

Answer (score 0):

i can find one more solution just add 2 pure white background .png imgaes in images folder of ui solution and save it as

sort_both.png ans sort_asc.png

basically this images are set the background to header of datatable

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this is what I settled with

```
<style>
    table.dataTable thead .sorting {
        background: url("/Content/DataTables/images/sort_both.png") no-repeat center right;
         } 
    table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
        background: url("/Content/DataTables/images/sort_asc.png") no-repeat center right;
        }
    table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
        background: url("/Content/DataTables/images/sort_desc.png") no-repeat center right;
       }
</style>
```

It just a quick fix without changing any thing in the supplied files. 
Dont forget to change 
 [ /Content/DataTables/images/ ] 
 accordingly